# Get HTML text with no tags around them

Tags: html, css, regex

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="uglyHtml">
    <br> <b>Lead</b>: <a href="#">John</a>
    <br> <b>Boss</b>: <a href="#">Bernard</a>
    <br> <b>Mascot</b>: Patrick
    <br> <b>Designer</b>: Jeanette
    <br> <b>Front</b>: <a href="#">Larry</a>
</div>
```

For exemple :

We can simply capture John, Bernard and Larry with : `#uglyHtml > a`
Lead, Boss, Mascot, Designer with : `#uglyHtml > b`

Now I need to capture `Patrick` & `Jeanette` who have no tags around them, for this I can **only** use CSS or/and regex

there is a way to do this ?

Comment: Neither CSS nor regex are *programming* languages. What's the actual technology you're using to write your processing code?

Comment: What do you mean "capture"? Are you just trying to style them? If so, put a default style for all the text in `#uglyHtml { styles here }` and worry about the rest with the other selectors.

Comment: @disinfor thanks to your reply, I use a program who just allow me to use css and regex to capture the entity I need.

Comment: @El-Burritos can you use JavaScript?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález A program who allow me to use css and regex to select the entity I need in the HTML body

Comment: @MohammadJavidi I can't, just css selector and regex

Comment: Can you show us the regex that you've tried? Even tho, using regex on HTML is not recommended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never use a regular expression to match the text, but seems like that is what your tool wants. Something like this would match the role and the person. This will break very easily.

```js
var html = document.querySelector("#uglyHtml").innerHTML

var re = /<b>([^<]+)<\/b>: (?:<a[^>]+>)?([^<\n]+)/g
let out = true
while (out) {
  out = re.exec(html)
  console.log(out)
}
```

```html
<div id="uglyHtml">
  <br> <b>Lead</b>: <a href="#">John</a>
  <br> <b>Boss</b>: <a href="#">Bernard</a>
  <br> <b>Mascot</b>: Patrick
  <br> <b>Designer</b>: Jeanette
  <br> <b>Front</b>: <a href="#">Larry</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
    #uglyHtml:not(a), #uglyHtml:not(b) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Why not just `#uglyHtml { styles }`?

Comment: @disinfor Cause I need to focus the entities Patrick and Jeanette, this solution #uglyHtml, return me all the text in the #uglyHtml div

Comment: @El-Burritos sure, but we still have no idea what you are trying to do. CSS is for styling. It doesn't get or "capture" information from the document.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your help, I figure it out with a simple regex:

```
<br> <b>.*<\/b>: ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/lGE5bY/3